# Why does isFinishing() behaves differently in entry point Activity (with android.intent.action.MAIN) and non entry point Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 types of `Activity` -

1. One acts as the entry point of the Application, with `android.intent.action.MAIN`.
2. Another activity is launched by the entry point activity.

They looks as the following

```
// Act as entry point of the application, with android.intent.action.MAIN
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.i(TAG, "MainActivity isFinishing() : " + this.isFinishing());
    }
}

// Launched by MainActivity.
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.i(TAG, "MainActivity2 isFinishing() : " + this.isFinishing());
    }
}
```

I notice that `this.isFinishing()` behaves differently in both Activity, when I tested via

1. Back button press
2. Home button press

Here's the observation

### MainActivity (Entry point Activity)

1. When back button pressed, `isFinishing()` returns false.
2. When home button pressed, `isFinishing()` returns false.

### MainActivity2 (Launched by MainActivity)

1. When back button pressed, `isFinishing()` returns **true**.
2. When home button pressed, `isFinishing()` returns false.

---

I want to differentiate between back button press, and home button press by using `isFinishing()` method. Now, I realize I can't do that in entry point Activity, because both scenarios returns the same `false`.

May I know, why does isFinishing() behaves differently in entry point Activity (with android.intent.action.MAIN) and non entry point Activity?

Thanks.

Comment: What Android API level are you testing this on?

Comment: My app is targeting API 30 (Android 11) and I run such test in Android 12. I just notice such new behavior is for Android 12 ( https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#back-press ). Is this norm? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected on all Android 12 and higher devices as per the [Behavior changes for all apps in Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#back-press):

> Android 12 changes the default handling of the system Back press on launcher activities that are at the root of their tasks. In previous versions, the system would finish these activities on Back press. In Android 12, the system now moves the activity and its task to the background instead of finishing the activity. The new behavior matches the current behavior when navigating out of an app using the Home button or gesture.

Therefore there is no way to tell the difference between the system back button and the home button on the root activity - they purposefully both put the activity in the exact same state in the exact same way. You shouldn't be trying to distinguish between the two as they are not meant to be treated any differently (i.e., you shouldn't clear any state or make any changes for one that you wouldn't also do for the other).

This only applies to the root activity of your task stack, which is why your other activities still show as `isFinishing()` when the back button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks. My initial thought is that, app targeting Android 11 which runs on Android 12 will behave in Android 11 way. Seem like my assumption is wrong.

Comment: That's exactly why there are two separate pages: one for changes that affect all apps and a separate one for changes that only come into affect when you target that version of Android. This is one of the former.